# VBA Excel Comparing rows

Tags: vba, excel, compare

I am trying to perform a Excel-based tool for my personal bank account. I have imported some bank operations in a sheet `Import` with 3 columns (`Date`, `Information`, `Amount`). I would like to compare a each line in `Import` to a collection already established in another sheet `Data`.

I have created a function to test (according to the date then the information if necessary and then again the amount if necessary) each line and return 0 if the operation is not present in the data collection and the row number within the data collection.

```
Function CompareRows(SingleRng As Range, CollectionRange As Range) As Integer
    'SingleRange : Date / Info / amount in on line
    'CollectionRange : Date / info / amount / ....(others) on many rows
    'Return 0 if SingleRng is not in CollectionRange, row number of data 
                                                  'collection if present.

    Dim row As Range
    For Each row In CollectionRange
        MsgBox row.Value

       ' If SingleRng(1, 1) = Rng_1(1, 1).Value Then
       '     CompareRows = irw
       ' Else
       '     irw = irw + 1
       ' End If
    Next
End Function
```

This function will be looped for each line in the `Import` sheet, but I can't loop on each date element first. This loop is run on each element of the `CollectionRange`. I tried to do `For Each row In CollectionRange.Rows`, but the `MsgBox` after does not work. How can I make this loop on each row?

Answer (score 0):

For looping over a range of rows `For Each row In CollectionRange.Rows` is correct.

The reason `MsgBox row.Value` then doesn't work is `row.Value` is an array.  To see one of the values in the array use something like `row.Cells(1,1).Value`

That said, be aware that looping over a range like this can be quite slow.  If your are not satisfied with the performance of your code, there are alternatives such as `AutoFilter`, `Find` and `Variant Arrays`